# Set ID on currently appended element

Tags: jquery

I have a `<script type="text/template>` which inner HTML I use to create new elements.
How can I additionally add an ID to those created elements?

```
<script type="text/template" id="element-template">
    <div class="element-container">
        <p>Template</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Desired outcome:

```
<div id="my-element" class="element-container">
   <p>Template</p>
</div>
```

Following code works, but I don't want to use `find('.element-container')` on the parent because the class could change in the future:

```
var template = $('#element-template').html();
$('#output').append(template).parent().find('.element-container').attr('id', 'my-element');​
```

Use can find a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RZrkB/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make the `template` variable hold a jquery object instead of the html.

That way you can [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone) it and directly add an id on it.

```
var template = $( $('#element-template').html() );

$('#output').append( template.clone().attr('id','my-element') );
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/RZrkB/3/

Comment: Ah, I was missing the outer wrapping with $()... Thanks!
But do I need to clone() it? It seems to be working fine without: http://jsfiddle.net/RZrkB/6/

Comment: @JohnB., it works fine without it for a single append.. my idea was that since it is a template you might want to reuse it...

Comment: I understand, seems to be the best solution to my case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to set the id attribute for the first child element you could do it using jQuery [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) like this:

```
var template = $('#element-template').html();
var $output = $('#output');
$output.append(template).children(':first').attr('id', 'my-element');​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/RZrkB/4/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find('div:first')`

```
$('#output').append($('#element-template').html())
.find('div:first').attr('id', 'my-element');​
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RZrkB/7/).